# ActiveX controls are disabled during design time in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, activex, mozilla

I am developing WPF windows application using VS 2008 and .NET 3.5. I am trying to use Mozilla Web browser activeX control in my application. I have added it to my tool box. The control is visible in tool box but it is disabled state. I am not able to use it during design time. This does not happen with normal Windows Form Application, I am able to use same control during design time.

Can anybody help me to understand this strange behavior?

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF doesn't directly support ActiveX controls.  You'll need Winforms to give it a hospitable runtime environment and leverage the auto-generated AxHost wrapper.  The WindowsFormHost control is available to embed winforms controls in a WPF window.  The walkthrough that shows the technique is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx).

Comment: Cool! In the context of your answer could you have a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859709/does-wpf-webbrowser-support-vlc-activex#comment20829397_14859709  10000000 thanks!!