# Does WPF WebBrowser support VLC ActiveX?

Tags: .net, wpf, browser, activex, vlc

What I need is to open **ANY** Web page that has implemented `VLC ActiveX under WPF WebBrowser.`

I just did a VERY simple page that works perfect under IE9/10.

But when I open it there is no any VLC :(

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title></title>

 </head>
<body>
    <object width="720" height="408" id='vlc2' events="True" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
        classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
        <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
            width="720" height="408" id="vlc1" />
        <param name="src" value="http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-52qL9xLP.mp4" />
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
        <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Like an alternative to test try to open [this](http://www.vlc.eu.pn/index.php) page under `WPF WebBrowser` and **NOTHING** happens.

*Any clue brothers and sisters?*

*P.S. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970906(v=vs.100).aspx  doesn't help...*

P.S. #2  I just tested [this](http://www.vlc.eu.pn/index.php) page  and also my page with WinForms WebBrowser control and it is not working :(  Does it mean that MS webBrowser control doesn't support ActiveX at all or VLC ActiveX control is limited somehow?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I believe the `WebBrowser` is just a wrapper around the currently installed version of Internet Explorer.  So you answer would be "depends", but you won't be able to guarantee that the ActiveX control would work on deployed systems.

Comment: I agree with @CodingGorilla. Have you tested using IE (in IE 7 rendering mode) itself on the same machine to make sure it's not a security or configuration problem?

Comment: @DocMax yes yes. I did it. U can see the source code of the page I did to test. I did it at the same computer.